# How can I merge all branches into one by dividing them into folders

Tags: git

I have a repository that has branches:

- main
- client
- server
- server2.0

How can I merge the client, server, server2.0 branches into the main branch, but so that the data from the branches is stored in a folder with the name of its old branch

P.S: If this is possible, how can I then update the files in main after changing one of the three branches?

Unfortunately I don't have any ideas

Comment: When you divided the components of your project into branches, [you have grossly misunderstood the purpose of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291997/6868543). I suggest to start all over again. Put `client` and `server` into separate *folders* in one branch, *main*, and then make another branch off of main, *server2.0*, where you make the changes in the folder `server` that advances only this component to the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add those branches as subtrees of main, assuming they don't share any common files with main and are completely independent. You can even preserve the history of each branch. But since you're adding subtrees of the local repository, you will probably want to delete those branches after so you don't accidentally tangle up your repo causing confusion and make it unmaintainable.

To add the subtrees, you'd do:

```
git checkout main
git subtree add -P client client
git subtree add -P server server
git subtree add -P server2.0 server2.0
```

`-P` specifies the name of the directory you want to put the subtree in and use the given ref/commit (the branch name in this case).

If you insist on keeping the branches and still be able to maintain them separately, you can checkout those branches and work with them like normal. But they will get out of sync with what main has the more you work with it. To update main with the changes made to the branches, you could `pull` the changes in just like it was a remote repo, except it's for the subtree. If you're working on main and want to push the changes out to the branches, you could push the changes.

```
git subtree pull -P client client         # similar to adding
```

You could do a lot of similar actions you would do for remotes, check the documentation.

Comment: On second thought, you might not want to actually delete the old branches, lest you might lose that commit history. I'm not sure if subtrees would necessarily keep those "alive" and not be lost to the gc. But you definitely should stop development on those branches and just work in main instead.